# Spotting the error in finding order and degree of differential equation whose solution is $(x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2 = a^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find order and degree of differential equation whose solution is: $(x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2 = a^2$ (where $a$ is a constant)

**Attempt:**

$x- h + yy' - ky' = 0 $

$\implies 1+ yy'' + (y')^2 - ky'' = 0 $

So,
 *order* $= 2$

*degree* $= 1$

But answer is:
order $ =2$ , degree $=2$

Comment: Your equation still contains $k$, and it is not of degree $1$.

Comment: If constants can remain, then the initial equation is of order $0$ and degree $2$ and that's it.

Comment: The question says that $a$ is a constant. Then what are $h$ and $k$ ???

Comment: @YvesDaoust Question doesn't say anything about them.

Comment: If $h,k$ can remain, the equation is $(x-h)+(y-k)y'=0$, first order, first degree.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

You need to eliminate three constants, and for this you will need to differentiate three times. Hence order $3$.

$$a^2=(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=a^2\to0=(x-h)+(y-k)y',$$

$$h=x+(y-k)y'\to0=1+y'^2+(y-k)y'',$$

$$k=\frac{1+y'^2}{y''}+y\to0=\left(\frac{y'^2+1}{y''}\right)'+1.$$